# Gradle Exception while running lint

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting an exception every time I run the Gradle task `lint`. The project has four build types and two flavors. The Gradle Version is 2.2.1 and the Android plugin version 1.1.3.
Any help would be appreciated.

The exception:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2070
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.substitute(Scope.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.superclass(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:1212)
    at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser$EcjResolvedClass.isSubclassOf(EcjParser.java:1025)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.CleanupDetector.checkResourceRecycled(CleanupDetector.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.CleanupDetector.visitMethod(CleanupDetector.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor$DelegatingJavaVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(JavaVisitor.java:1314)
    at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:114)
    at lombok.ast.BinaryExpression.accept(BinaryExpression.java:131)
    at lombok.ast.ExpressionStatement.accept(ExpressionStatement.java:63)
    at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
    at lombok.ast.Try.accept(Try.java:107)
    at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
    at lombok.ast.MethodDeclaration.accept(MethodDeclaration.java:240)
    at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
    at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
    at lombok.ast.CompilationUnit.accept(CompilationUnit.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor.visitFile(JavaVisitor.java:263)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkJava(LintDriver.java:1491)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:1026)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:882)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:433)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:374)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:130)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.runLint(Lint.groovy:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.this$4$runLint(Lint.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$this$4$runLint$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintSingleVariant(Lint.groovy:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$lintSingleVariant$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 55 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference in your case... but did you run with `gradlew lint`, or `gradle lint`? I typed by accident `gradle` and also had some problems, but it built successfully when using the gradle wrapper (`gradlew`) instead.

Comment: I've tried building with `gradle` and `gradlew`  from the cmd and also with Android Studio. The result was the same.